# ADM201 - explaination for an answer

Tags: salesforce

Sales representatives at Universal Containers need assistance from product managers when selling certain products. Product managers do not have access to opportunities, but need to gain access when they are assisting with a specific deal. How can a system administrator accomplish this?
   A. Notify the product manager using opportunity update reminders.
   B. Enable opportunity teams and allow users to add the product manager. 
   C. Use similar opportunities to show opportunities related to the product manager.
   D. Enable account teams and allow users to add the product manager.

This is the question from the sample paper. I'm a newbie, i couldn't understand how the answer is B.

what does 'Enable opportunity teams' mean ? && how to 'allow users to add the product manager'

Answer (score 0):

Opportunity Teams are a feature of salesforce. They allow you to modify the default sharing model (which might be set to private for Opportunities), and when you add users to an opportunity team, those users are given read and/or read/write access to that opportunity. I believe this is managed automatically behind the scenes by Salesforce via a sharing rule.